# Chop off text when it reaches certain word in Python

Tags: python, slice, tableofcontents, chop

I'm using Python and I have an HTML-code which I want to chop off as soon as it reaches the word "toc", but I can't figure out how to do, anyone having some nice ideas?

Comment: How  it must be chop off? can you show an example?

Comment: Would you put more details in your question? What do you have so far?

Comment: for example turn this
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>IBM - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title>


into this 

<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">
<head>
<meta charset="

because it found the word "UTF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, something like the following works

```
s = "some string toc remainder of string"

s = s[:s.find('toc')]

print s  # some string
```

But be aware that this will catch words like "stock" -- so there's likely a better approach depending on your specifics.

Comment: Thank you! It worked with searching for 'id="toc"' for my purpose :D

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `split` :

```
>>> s="""<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> <title>IBM - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title> <meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki 1.25wmf19" />"""
>>> s.split('UTF')[0]
'<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs"> <head> <meta charset="'
```